# Bijective group homomorphisms are isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Why are all bijective group homomorphisms $\phi: G \to H$ automatically isomorphisms? That is, their inverses are also  homomorphisms.

I have seen this fact mentioned before, but never a proof.

We need to show that $\phi^{-1}(ab) = \phi^{-1}(a) \phi^{-1}(b)$ for all $a, b \in G$… no idea where to start.

Comment: Please try to prove this and show us how far you got.

Comment: I'm confident this has been asked here before but, oddly enough, I haven't found a duplicate!

Comment: A convenient property of bijections is: $x=y$ iff $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$. Hence, you can apply $\phi$ on both sides of your equation and prove that instead.

Comment: @chi Forgive me if I’m wrong, but if we were to go down that line, we would have to check all our are steps are reversible for it to be considered a correct proof? And the property you pointed out more or less shows the reversibility or the non-trivial steps.

Comment: You don't have to use both directions of the "iff". You have an equation to prove, $x=y$. To prove that, it's enough to prove $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$. It does not matter how you prove that second equation. Once you have done that, you get the original thesis $x=y$.

Comment: @Shaun [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752549) [Other duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570698/if-f-is-a-group-homomorphism-is-the-inverse-image-f-1-also-a-group-homom?noredirect=1). Others can be found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cphi%5E%7B-1%7D(ab)%20%3D%20%5Cphi%5E%7B-1%7D(a)%20%5Cphi%5E%7B-1%7D(b)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse of a bijective map is bijective. We must show that for all $x$ and $y\in H$,
$$\phi ^{-1}(x) \phi ^{-1} (y) = \phi  ^{-1}(xy)$$Set $a = \phi ^{-1}(x), b = \phi ^{-1} (y)$ and $ c = \phi ^{-1} (xy)$.  Since $\phi $ is a homomorphism,
$$\phi (ab) = \phi (a)\phi (b) = x y = \phi (c) \Rightarrow \phi ^{-1}(x)\phi ^{-1}(y)=\phi ^{-1}(xy)$$

Comment: As predicted above by Shaun, it was a megadupe.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varphi:G\to H$ be an bijective homomorphism. Then $\varphi^{-1}$ is a bijection. Let $h,h'\in H$. It remains to show that

$$\varphi^{-1}(hh')=\varphi^{-1}(h)\varphi^{-1}(h').$$

Since $\varphi^{-1}$ is a bijection, there exist $g,g'\in G$ such that

$$g=\varphi^{-1}(h), g'=\varphi^{-1}(h').$$

Now

$$\begin{align}
\varphi^{-1}(hh')&=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(g)\varphi(g'))\\
&=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(gg'))\tag{1}\\
&=(\varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi)(gg')\\
&=\operatorname{id}_G(gg')\\
&=gg'\\
&=\varphi^{-1}(h)\varphi^{-1}(h'),
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ holds since $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: As you predicted above, it was a megadupe.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $G$ and $H$ are groups is irrelevant. The result holds for all sets with a binary operation.

Let $A$ and $X$ be sets, with operations that we denote by multiplication. No further property is assumed.

A homomorphism $\varphi\colon A\to X$ is a map such that, for every $a,b\in A$, $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.

If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, that is, a bijective homomorphism, then also $\varphi^{-1}$ is a (bijective) homomorphism, hence an isomorphism.

Proof. Let $x,y\in X$. Then we have
$$
\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x)\varphi^{-1}(y))=\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x))\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(y))=xy
$$
and therefore
$$
\varphi^{-1}(xy)=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x)\varphi^{-1}(y)))=\varphi^{-1}(x)\varphi^{-1}(y)
$$

It's a useful exercise to prove that if $A$ is a group under the given operation and $\varphi\colon A\to X$ is an isomorphism, then also $X$ is a group.

The result extends to $n$-ary operations in the same way. You don't need to prove it for rings, fields, and even vector spaces, if you see them as sets with a binary operation + and a set of unary operations (the multiplications by a scalar).

Comment: I really enjoy the generality of this answer.

Comment: I'm surprised by your third paragraph; this is just a matter of convention, but I've always seen "isomorphism" to mean "bijective morphism whose converse function is also a morphism", rather than just "bijective morphism", so I expected your third paragraph to be "If $\varphi$ is a bijective homomorphism, then also $\varphi^{-1}$ is a (bijective) homomorphism, hence $\varphi$ is an isomorphism".

Comment: @Stef To be honest, I’ve (almost) always seen the definition I gave, coupled with the remark that the inverse is also a homomorphism. This is true when only operations are involved; it’s not true when also relations are present (posets, for instance).

Comment: As predicted above by Shaun, it was a megadupe.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi:G \rightarrow H$ is a bijective group homomorphism, then we can show its inverse $\phi^{-1}: H \rightarrow G$ is also a group homomorphism.

Let $h,h' \in H$ be arbitrary. Then $\phi(g)=h$ and $\phi(g')=h'$ for some $g,g' \in G$. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $\phi(g+g') =\phi(g) + \phi(g')=h+h'$.

Thus, $g+g'=\phi^{-1}(h+h')$.

Therefore, $\phi^{-1}(h) +\phi^{-1}(h')=\phi^{-1}(h+h')$.

Comment: The notation $+$ is reserved for abelian groups, usually.

Comment: As predicted above by Shaun, it was a megadupe.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$1_{G}\ \in\ G$$ $$1_{H}\ \in\ H$$ be the two groups’ respective identity elements and let $$\mu_{G}\ \colon\ G\times G\to G$$ $$\mu_{H}\ \colon\ H\times H\to H$$ be their respective multiplication maps (as functions of sets).

As $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $$\phi\left(1_{G}\right)\ = \ 1_{H}$$ $$\phi\ \circ\ \mu_{G}\ =\ \mu_{H}\ \circ\ \left(\phi\times\phi\right).$$ It follows (by bare definition) that
\begin{align*}
   \phi^{-1}\left(1_{H}\right)\ &=\ \phi^{-1}\left(\phi\left(1_{G}\right)\right)\\
    &=\ 1_{G}\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    \phi^{-1}\ \circ\ \mu_{H}\ &=\ \phi^{-1}\ \circ\ \left(\mu_{H}\ \circ\ \left(\phi\times\phi\right)\right)\ \circ\ \left(\phi^{-1}\times\phi^{-1}\right)\\
    &=\ \phi^{-1}\ \circ\ \left(\phi\ \circ\ \mu_{G}\right)\ \circ\ \left(\phi^{-1}\times\phi^{-1}\right)\\
    &=\ \mu_{G}\ \circ\ \left(\phi^{-1}\times\phi^{-1}\right)
\end{align*}
and thus that $\phi^{-1}$ is itself (by bare definition) a homomorphism, as claimed.

---

(The above is a shadow of the more general fact that a natural transformation is invertible iff it’s componentwise invertible.)

Comment: As predicted above by Shaun, it was a megadupe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-line proof (so to speak).

$$\begin{align}
\phi^{-1} (a b)
&= \phi^{-1} \Big (\phi \big (\phi^{-1}(a) \big) \ \phi \big(\phi^{-1}(b) \big) \Big) \\
&= \phi^{-1} \Big (\phi \big (\phi^{-1}(a) \ \phi^{-1}(b) \big) \Big) \\
&= \phi^{-1}(a) \ \phi^{-1}(b)
\end{align}$$

Comment: As predicted above by Shaun, it was a megadupe.